# passing query param to REST service which is dynamic in nature in denodo

Tags: denodo

I need to call REST API from DENODO (I use denodo express 7) with dynamic query param. This query param value would come from another JDBC data source view so that I can straightaway limit the results.

I have tried using interpolation variables, for example:
`http://<hostname:port>/path?id=@{viewname.transaction_id}` but it goes as `null` always, not sure is this correct way of accessing the view fields?